# Integral extension of domains implies algebraic extension of their fraction fields

Tags: extension-field, integral-extensions

If A $\subseteq B$ are domains and $B$ is integral over $A$, then is $Frac(B)$ algebraic over $Frac(A)$?  Ia it because of the following:

Any element of $Frac(B)$ is of the form $b/t$ with $b,t \in B, t\neq 0$, and if $b, t$ are algebraic over $Frac(A)$ (which they are), then so is $b/t$ because $Frac(A) \subseteq Frac(A)(b,t)$ is an algebraic extension (and $b/t$ is in there).

Comment: Absolutely correct!

Comment: I am studying the same problem. I have a doubt. Why $b/t$ is in $Frac(A)(b,t)$, the set of combinatons of fractions on $A$ and $b$, $t$? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Na'omi: not sure if it is helpful now, but b/t is in there because Frac(A)(b,t) is a field. It is similar to how we add $\sqrt 2$ to $Q$. (b and t both are integral over A, hence algebraic over Frac(A))

Comment: @student, thank you anyway so much. At that time I did not know if by definition the extension is a field (is it, right...?). Many thanks for attention.

Comment: It is a field because we are adjoining algebraic elements to a field.